# How do I use the ggmap library's get_map function inside of knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, ggmap

All of my R code runs as expected in a standalone script.  Once inside an R Markdown file the get_map() call breaks down.

```
map <- get_map(location = 'minneapolis', zoom = 9)
```

I get an error:

> label: unnamed-chunk-2
>   Warning in sink() : no sink to remove
>   label: unnamed-chunk-2
>   Error in process_file(text) :
>     Quitting from lines 53-64: Error in close.connection(con) : invalid connection
>   Calls: knit -> process_file
>   Execution halted
>   knitr terminated with status 1

Any ideas why knitr and get_map aren't playing nice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out the problem. The root reason is `ggmap` was being "rude" to `closeAllConnections()` in four of its functions: `mapdist()`, `geocode()`, `revgeocode()` and `route()`; `knitr` uses the [`evaluate` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evaluate/index.html) to evaluate R code, which opens text connections to record R output. Because `ggmap` has closed all connections, `evaluate` will not be able to close its connections again, which caused the error you saw. See https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/blob/master/R/watcher.r for details.

Normally one should be *explicit* about which connections to close using the `close()` function, and it is dangerous to use `closeAllConnections()` because this may close connections which are not supposed to be closed. I do not understand why the author has to use it, and I guess you need to report this issue to him. Finally we should be able to run this without errors:

```
library(evaluate); library(ggmap)
evaluate("map <- get_map(location = 'minneapolis', zoom = 9)")
```

Comment: The main problem (as described by Yihui) is now fixed in the dev version, it should be up in a few days.

Comment: @dkahle thanks! why not push the changes to Github as well? :)