# isIncomplete(con) error when knitting pdf

Tags: rstudio, knitr

I am able to run the following example script from the [`SWSamp`](https://sites.google.com/a/statistica.it/gianluca/swsamp) package fine in the console, but I get an "isIncomplete(con)" error when knitting to PDF. This package requires use of at least 2 cores, and I'm wondering if this connection error is related to trying to run in parallel.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
  install.packages("http://www.statistica.it/gianluca/SWSamp/SWSamp_0.3.tar.gz", type="source", dependencies=TRUE, repos=NULL)
  library(SWSamp)
```

```{r}
  mu1=0.3
  b.trt=-0.3875
  sigma.e=1.55
  J=5
  K=20
  sig.level=0.05
  n.sims=10
  rho=0.5
  pow.cont <- sim.power(I=14, J=J, H=NULL, K=K, rho=rho, mu=mu1, sigma.e=sigma.e,
                        b.trt=b.trt, formula=NULL, n.sims=n.sims, 
                        sig.level=sig.level, n.cores=2)
  pow.cont$power
```
````

> Quitting from lines 16-28 (test.Rmd)  Error in isIncomplete(con) :
>   invalid connection Calls:  ... evaluate_call ->
>   handle_output ->  -> isIncomplete Quitting from lines 16-28
>   (test.Rmd)  Error in isOpen(con) : invalid connection Calls:
>    ... in_dir -> evaluate -> evaluate_call ->  ->
>   isOpen Error in close.connection(con) : invalid connection Calls:
>    ->  -> close -> close.connection Execution
>   halted

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.1

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] SWSamp_0.3     lme4_1.1-12    Matrix_1.2-7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8       knitr_1.15.1      magrittr_1.5      splines_3.3.2     MASS_7.3-45      
 [6] doParallel_1.0.10 lattice_0.20-34   foreach_1.4.3     minqa_1.2.4       stringr_1.1.0    
[11] tools_3.3.2       parallel_3.3.2    grid_3.3.2        nlme_3.1-128      htmltools_0.3.5  
[16] iterators_1.0.8   yaml_2.1.14       rprojroot_1.1     digest_0.6.10     nloptr_1.0.4     
[21] codetools_0.2-15  evaluate_0.10     rmarkdown_1.3     stringi_1.1.2     compiler_3.3.2   
[26] backports_1.0.4
```

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162824/how-do-i-use-the-ggmap-librarys-get-map-function-inside-of-knitr) gives some hint about possible ways a different package might be closing connections, but the `evaluate()` solution does not work for me.

Comment: The `sim.power` function does use the `closeAllConnections()` function which is probably interfering with knitr.

Comment: my temporary solution is to redefine the `sim.power()` function with the `closeAllConnections()` call commented out. I don't know if this has adverse effects, but seems to run for me. Better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sim.power()` function runs `closeAllConnections()`, which interferes with knitr according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162824/how-do-i-use-the-ggmap-librarys-get-map-function-inside-of-knitr). The solution in this answer was to wrap the expression in quotes and the `evaluate()` function, but it did not work for me.

As a temporary solution, I redefined the `sim.power()` function with the `closeAllConnections()` call commented out. I don't know if this has adverse effects, but seems to run for me. Happy to accept better answers.